# Issues with adding to vectors with enums

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, enums

I recently got stuck while making a C++11/SDL game engine, and I can use some advice.
Ideally, what I want to do is the following:

1. create enumeration representing all sprites to add to a spritebank
2. create a vector of filenames, and using the enumeration add each filename to the vector
3. go through all loaded filenames, and using the enum create sprites with specific properties

but the second step (the files.emplace() functions) gives [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKPC6.png) and the third step (switch(sprite_file)) gives different errors based on if I use [this->sprite_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9xLX.png) or [sprite_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js2YK.png). Any ideas on how to make this idea work? The code I used is below (feel free to say if there's any info missing)

```
//abstracted application class that starts the program//
std::vector<std::string> files;

class App : public Event
{
    private:
        bool Running; //Running flag

        enum sprite_file
        {
            SPRITE_RING1 = 0,
            SPRITE_RING2 = 1,
            SPRITE_END = 2
        };

        SDL_Window* graphicsWindow; //The window
        SDL_Renderer* graphicsRenderer; //The renderer
        TTF_Font* globalFont; //The global font

        Timer capTimer; //Frames per second cap timer

        SpriteBank rings; //Collection of sprites
        std::string currentSprite; //Filename of sprite in use
[...]
//abstracted initialization function within App//
//Initialize spritebank
   if(!rings.Init(graphicsRenderer))
   {
      printf("Failed to load sprites!");
   }

   //Add two sprites
   files.emplace(SPRITE_RING1, "media/img/ring/ring1.png");
   files.emplace(SPRITE_RING2, "media/img/ring/ring2.png");

   //Add two sprites
   for(auto filename : files)
   {
      switch(this->sprite_file)
      {
         case SPRITE_RING1:
         {
            rings.AddSprite(filename,
                        40,
                        40,
                        40,
                        20,
                        20);
            break;
         }

         case SPRITE_RING2:
         {
            rings.AddSprite(filename,
                        40,
                        40,
                        40,
                        20,
                        20);
            break;
         }
         default: continue; break;
      }
   }

   currentSprite = SPRITE_RING1;
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your errors. Copy 'n' paste the errors into your question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `files.emplace(SPRITE_RING1, "media/img/ring/ring1.png");`? You're basically passing an enum and a string literal to the constructor of `std::string`. What are you expecting `std::string`'s constructor to do with those two arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two obvious issues:

A `std::vector` does not work like a `std::map`. Even then I'm not sure if you have more than these 3 enum elements. Maybe you want to use a structure inside of the vector ?

Also you cannot switch the `enum`s declaration name. You have to switch a variable having a value of the enum to be able to enter the switch, and to be able to compile.

```
//example:
sprite_file myVar = SPRITE_RING1;
switch (myVar)
{
    //...
}
```

Also you cannot assign the enum's integer value to a `std::string`.

```
currentSprite = SPRITE_RING1
```

The simplest way is to create another variable of the enum type.